# change date format using Moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I am working on `knockoutjs`. I am using `Moment.js` to format the database date column. I used the format below.

By default I am getting the date as `1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM`, so I used the following format:

`<div data-bind="text: moment(JoinedDate).format('L')"></div>`

which is giving me `1/4/2013`, but I need the format as `04-Jan-14`. So can some one help me to get this right?

Comment: Sounds easy, <div data-bind="text: moment(JoinedDate).format('DD-MMM-YY')"></div>, is that what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the docs it should be [format("DD-MMM-YY")](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)